# conditional filtering in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have such a matrix:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 ['a','b','c','d','e']
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 [1,1,1,0,0,0]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

And I want to make this query: `pos_data = data[data[:, 5] == 1]`

But I get this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

How can I achieve to do that?

Comment: Can you give a sample of data ? It seems to works on my test (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have an other error in your workflow ? It seems to work in my test :

```
data = np.random.randint(1, 23, (22136, 27))
data.shape
# (22136,27)
res = data[data[..., 5] == 1]
res.shape
# (1001, 27)
res
#array([[21, 10, 18, ..., 10, 12, 20],
#       [ 7, 20, 12, ..., 10, 13,  7],
#       [ 1, 12,  4, ...,  6, 19, 19],
#       ..., 
#       [ 8, 10, 18, ...,  4, 15,  8],
#       [ 1, 13,  4, ..., 22, 13, 21],
#       [11,  3, 18, ..., 18, 10,  5]])
```

Or given your other example :

```
mat = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
               [1,2,3,4,5,6],
               [1,2,3,4,5,6],
               [1,1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,2,3,4,5,6],
               [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

mat[mat[:, 2] == 1]
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Or maybe it is not what you are looking for ?

I also guess you can avoid this kind of error by using a different notation (there is some details on the [numpy documentation about indexing/slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) ) :

```
In [20]: mat = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], ['a','b','c','d','e'], [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

In [22]: mat[2,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-322-142bfc45a932>", line 1, in <module>
    mat[2,:]

IndexError: too many indices for array

In [23]: mat[2,...]
Out[23]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=object)
```